# BackBox 4.7 - no wlan0 and eth0 interfaces

Tags: linux, ethernet, wlan

I've just installed BackBox 4.7 2016. On live backbox while it was installing, I had access to various nearby Access Points and so I had eth0 interface. When installation was in the half of its job, my wifi suddenly disappeared. I  tried bunch of commands which I don't remember now, but I remember typing `sudo rfkill unblock all`, restarting network-service and so on. After that, my second interface eth0 has disappeared. My interfaces in Win7 work great.

When I type `sudo ifconfig` it only shows local loopback interface and nothing else. I've also installed linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14 and nothing happened after reboot. Any suggestions, guys?

Here some info:

```
grand@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for grand: 
lo 

   Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:112993 (112.9 KB)  TX bytes:112993 (112.9 KB)`


grand@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

grand@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

grand@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex [1022:1510]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 7340] [1002:9808]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio [1002:1314]
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Port [1022:1512]
00:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Port [1022:1513]
00:10.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7812] (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7804]
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:780b] (rev 14)
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:780e] (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge [1022:780f] (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7809] (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 [1022:1700] (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1 [1022:1701]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2 [1022:1702]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3 [1022:1703]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4 [1022:1704]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6 [1022:1718]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5 [1022:1716]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7 [1022:1719]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0702:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

grand@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~$ lsmod | grep b43
b43                   397312  0 
bcma                   49152  1 b43
mac80211              651264  1 b43
cfg80211              487424  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    57344  1 b43

grand@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~$ dmesg | grep b43
[   15.446887] Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
[   15.446903] b43: probe of bcma0:1 failed with error -524
```

**Update**

After runing : `update-pciids`

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn   Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01) Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 
[14e4:0608] Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

`

Comment: welcome to U&L , please run `update-pciids` then `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Hello! I did that and got this:
`root@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~# update-pciids
root@grand-Lenovo-B575e:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0608]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
`

Comment: Moreover, I've installed fwcutter and my broadcom drivers. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the [`bcmwl-kernel-source`](https://launchpad.net/~longsleep/+archive/ubuntu/bcmwl) package :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/bcmwl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Unload conflicting driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the `wl` module

```
sudo modprobe wl
```